# Assume both r and s are rational then $\frac{r}{s}\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: rational-numbers

Currently done with showing for both r+s and r $\times s$ rational.

Now stuck with the following part; If we know that r and s are both rationals what could we say about

**$\frac{r}{s}$**

Assume both r and s are rationals.

Then we would have by definition r = **$\frac{a}{b}$** where a and b are integers and b $\neq$ 0

Similarly;
s = **$\frac{c}{d}$** where c and d are integers and d $\neq$ 0

**$\frac{r}{s}$** = (**$\frac{a}{b}$**) /(**$\frac{c}{d}$**)

Hence  **$\frac{r}{s}$** = (a $\times d$)/ (b $\times c$)

Since ad and bc are integers, numerator and denumerator are both integers. Integers divided by integers are rational ?

Is this valid proof ?

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: Not a lot, unless you also know $s\neq 0$.

Comment: I have updated the original question about my approach.

Comment: Your (just added) proof is fine.

Comment: No, the proof is invalid, because you forgot that $s$ might be $0$. In this case, $c=0$, so $\frac{r}{s}=\frac{ad}{bc}$ is undefined. (Integers divided by _non-zero_ integers are rational!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a valid proof.

The only "error" that may be corrected is that you must assume $s\in\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$, because if $s=0$ then $r/s$ is undefined and consequently we get that $r/s\notin\mathbb{Q}$.

So, as conclussion for your proof:
$$r\in\mathbb{Q}\phantom{a}, \phantom{a}s\in\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\} \Longrightarrow \frac{r}{s}\in\mathbb{Q}.$$

Comment: I see, thank you !